# Spam accounts created automatically

Tags: 7, performance, captcha

I need some urgent suggestion. In my live site a lot of spam users are being created every few minutes. I will install captcha and MOLLOM but I need to delete the spam users. How can I identify them and how do I prevent this from happening again?

Please advice

Comment: The second part of the question is a dupe of [this one](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/38942/how-to-delete-blocked-users-in-bulk)

Answer (score 2):

How to prevent it from happening you already know:

- Anti-spam tools like Mollom
- Captcha

For mass deletion, [use Views to list them](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1709/using-views-how-to-list-users-and-have-the-number-of-nodes-created-by-them):

- Create a new users view (add new view, show: "Users"),
- add relationships you feel will be helpful to identify spammers, like "User: Content authored".
- add filters based on these relationships, like

  - Created unreasonably high amount of content or no content at all,
  - only users with account younger than the spam wave,
  - et cetera;
- [use VBO to actually delete unwanted ones](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1792/how-to-delete-1600-users-and-2500-posts#1794) - just check them, or use select all and uncheck good guys. Of course good filters will reduce number of good gu